# Display a list with corresponding numbers for user to select

Tags: java

```
//PASSWORD Y/N LOOP
        //Does not want to add password, will list stores websites and corresponding numbers
        while (yesNo == 'n') {
            //WEBSITE LIST MENU LOOP
//FIXME website num is exponentially increasing everytime no is entered.
            for (i = 0; i < (websites.getwebList().size()); i++) {
                System.out.print(websiteNum + " - ");
                System.out.println(websites.getwebList().get(i));
                websiteNum = websiteNum + 1;
            }
            //Asks for user input of number of website they want to access
            System.out.println("Enter the number of the website you want to access:");
            userNum = scnr.nextInt();
            j = userNum - 1;
            //j corresponds to index in array since userNum is i + 1
//PRINT WEBSITE LIST
            while (alwaysTrue == true)
            {
//FIXME always results in cannot access
                if (userNum == websiteNum)
                {
                    System.out.println(websites.getwebList().get(j));
                    System.out.println(usernames.getuserNameList().get(j));
                    System.out.println(passwords.getPassList().get(j));
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Cannot access, try again.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }}}
```

I am currently trying to make a password manager, I am having trouble with the last part and creating the list for user selection. The plan is to have it look something like this
1 - website1.com
2 - website2.com

and when the user enters the corresponding number it will print the username and password that goes with the website as well.

I am currently trying to make a password manager, I am having trouble with the last part and creating the list for user selection. The plan is to have it look something like this
1 - website1.com
2 - website2.com

and when the user enters the corresponding number it will print the username and password that goes with the website as well.

currently what is happening is the list will print, but none of the selections can ever be accessed and when it loops they numbers will exponentially increase

1 - website1.com
2 - website2.com

2 - website1.come
4 - website2.com

Answer (score 0):

> when it loops they numbers will exponentially increase

You're incrementing websiteNum in the first for loop, but it never resets back to zero. Every time you enter that loop you're increasing it's value. It's not 'exponentially' increasing, but it always increasing without resetting back to zero.